# Pandas - Set value in column by looking up in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that have the following structure.

Dataframe A:

| id | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | null |
| 1 | 2021-09-02 | null |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | null |
| 2 | 2021-09-02 | null |
| 3 | 2021-09-01 | null |
| 3 | 2021-09-02 | null |

Dataframe B:

| id | price |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 300 |

I need to set the price in dataframe A, for each id, to the same value as the id has in dataframe B, regardless of the date in dataframe A.

So expected result is the following:

| id | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-09-02 | 100 |
| 2 | 2021-09-01 | 200 |
| 2 | 2021-09-02 | 200 |
| 3 | 2021-09-01 | 300 |
| 3 | 2021-09-02 | 300 |

The data set is very large so need something efficient.

Happy to hear your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.merge`:

```
>>> dfA.drop(columns='price').merge(dfB, on='id', how='left')

   id        date  price
0   1  2021-09-01    100
1   1  2021-09-02    100
2   2  2021-09-01    200
3   2  2021-09-02    200
4   3  2021-09-01    300
5   3  2021-09-02    300
```

Please read carefully: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Did not know merge existed. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `set_index` and fillna:

```
>>> df1.set_index('id').fillna({'price': df2.set_index('id')['price']}).reset_index()
   id        date  price
0   1  2021-09-01  100.0
1   1  2021-09-02  100.0
2   2  2021-09-01  200.0
3   2  2021-09-02  200.0
4   3  2021-09-01  300.0
5   3  2021-09-02  300.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

***mapping*** may be useful as well:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id","date", "price"],
                   data=[[1, "2021-09-01", "N/A"],
                         [1, "2021-09-02", "N/A"],
                         [2, "2021-09-01", "N/A"],
                         [2, "2021-09-02", "N/A"],
                         [3, "2021-09-01", "N/A"],
                         [3, "2021-09-02", "N/A"]])

dfB = pd.DataFrame(columns=["id", "price"],
                   data=[[1, 100],
                         [2, 200],
                         [3, 300]])

map_dict = dfB.set_index("id").to_dict()["price"]
dfA["price"] = dfA["id"]
dfA["price"] = dfA["price"].map(map_dict)
```